# Unable to find xmpp.hrl and ejabberd.hrl in ejabberd-19.02

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am new with Ejabberd and Erlang and I am trying to add [this module](https://github.com/diamondbybold/ejabberd_mod_offline_post/blob/master/mod_offline_post.erl). I made the changes like I replace the jlib.hrl with xmpp.hrl and replace the packet by the message as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42106413/6544777) my issue is whenever I am trying to compile it say xmpp.hrl and ejabberd.hrl is not found how can I solve this issue.

I want to send the FCM notification to the offline user if some trying to send a message to him. am I doing right? or there have some other best ways to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ejabberd.hrl was removed a year ago: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/fd8e07af4789be362a61755ea47f216baeb64989

Download ejabberd source code, copy mod_offline_post.erl to the src/ dir, and make your changes, including those two:

```
diff --git a/src/mod_offline_post.erl b/src/mod_offline_post.erl
index 312278dc0..f4e6f79a1 100644
--- a/src/mod_offline_post.erl
+++ b/src/mod_offline_post.erl
@@ -13,8 +13,7 @@

 -define(PROCNAME, ?MODULE).

--include("ejabberd.hrl").
--include("jlib.hrl").
+-include("xmpp.hrl").
 -include("logger.hrl").
 -include("mod_muc_room.hrl").
```

Then compile and install ejabberd.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the given URL and download the source code from https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/0bd4d1aade28a329edf812095adb7e2c99495fee since this source code contains the ejabberd.hrl file and if I add mod_offline_post.erl in this source code then my server version will be 18.04, not 19.03 did I get everything you want to explain here or I understand something else please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Right. You have two alternatives: download ejabberd 18.04 and include mod_offline_post.erl, doing some changes. Or download ejabberd 19.02 and include mod_offline_post.erl, doing several changes.